# How to get back my Mainwindow in Pyqt5 setcentralWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to get back my MainWindow ?
From my MainWindow. If I Press either the  **"Open Left Box"** button or **"Open Right Box"** button, it's worked and at the same time, If I press the **"Back"** Button from Left Box, nothing will happen. How to obtain the main window? (Simply, I want to know how to set Layouts and remove layouts  in **setcentral Widgets**)

```
import sys,os

from PyQt5.QtGui import  *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Class_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.widgets()
        self.layouts()

    def widgets(self):
        self.Masterbtn = QPushButton("Master")
        self.transbtn  = QPushButton("tanscation")
        self.reportbtn = QPushButton("Reports")

        self.masterlbl = QLabel("Master Label")
        self.translbl = QLabel("transcation label")
        self.reportlbl = QLabel("Report Label")

        self.leftboxbtn = QPushButton("Open Left Box")
        self.leftboxbtn.clicked.connect(self.leftboxopn)
        self.rightboxbtn = QPushButton("Open Right Box")
        self.rightboxbtn.clicked.connect(self.rightboxopn)

        self.backbtn =QPushButton("Back")
        self.backbtn.clicked.connect(self.mainwindow)

    def layouts(self):
        self.mainbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainbox.addWidget(self.leftboxbtn)
        self.mainbox.addWidget(self.rightboxbtn)


        self.leftbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.leftbox.addWidget(self.Masterbtn)
        self.leftbox.addWidget(self.transbtn)
        self.leftbox.addWidget(self.reportbtn)
        self.leftbox.addWidget(self.backbtn)

        self.rightbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.rightbox.addWidget(self.masterlbl)
        self.rightbox.addWidget(self.translbl)
        self.rightbox.addWidget(self.reportlbl)
        # self.rightbox.addWidget(self.backbtn)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.mainbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def leftboxopn(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Left Box ")
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.leftbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def rightboxopn(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Right Box")
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.rightbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def mainwindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.mainbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = Class_MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ =="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot "get back" anything, because everytime you use `setCentralWidget()` the *existing* widget gets deleted, as the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget):

> Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time.

When you call `setCentralWidget()` on another widget, the previous is *completely deleted*, including all its children. When a Qt object is deleted, all its child objects gets deleted along with it, and the result is that the `self.mainbox` you created in the beginning doesn't exist any more (the *python* object exists, but remember that PyQt objects are only a *reference* to the actual Qt objects: a Qt object can be deleted if Qt requires it, even if the python reference still exists).

In substance (and, in any case), you should not replace the central widget everytime, but use a *paged* widget like QStackedWidget as the central widget instead, and then switch to the other interfaces using its functions: [`setCurrentIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) or [`setCurrentWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentWidget).

In order to properly use it, all child widgets must be added to a QWidget container, which will then be added as individual "pages" to QStackedWidget:

```
class Class_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def layouts(self):
        self.mainContainer = QWidget()
        self.mainbox = QVBoxLayout(self.mainContainer)
        self.mainbox.addWidget(self.leftboxbtn)
        self.mainbox.addWidget(self.rightboxbtn)


        self.leftContainer = QWidget()
        self.leftbox = QVBoxLayout(self.leftContainer)
        self.leftbox.addWidget(self.Masterbtn)
        self.leftbox.addWidget(self.transbtn)
        self.leftbox.addWidget(self.reportbtn)
        self.leftbox.addWidget(self.backbtn)

        self.rightContainer = QWidget()
        self.rightbox = QVBoxLayout(self.rightContainer)
        self.rightbox.addWidget(self.masterlbl)
        self.rightbox.addWidget(self.translbl)
        self.rightbox.addWidget(self.reportlbl)
        # self.rightbox.addWidget(self.backbtn)

        self.stackedWidget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.mainContainer)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.leftContainer)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.rightContainer)

    def leftboxopn(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Left Box ")
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.leftContainer)

    def rightboxopn(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Right Box")
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.rightContainer)

    def mainwindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.mainContainer)
```